# Tracking medium of user on primary domain firing an event in a third-party iFrame

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, iframe

Recently one of the websites I work on have added a form to their website that uses a third-party iFrame.

We do have access to the third party code and have added GTM. in GTM I have managed to successfully implement cross domain tracking and trigger an event when confirmation page inside the iFrame is viewed. This data is then sent to GA and triggers a goal completion.
I've also excluded the third party domain from the referral list.

This is good but we're now unable to track if the users came from PPC, Organic, Email etc. I'm struggling to find sources online.

Question: How do I track the source of the user on the original domain when triggering an event in a third-party iFrame for analysing goal completions by channel?

Answer (score 1):

This is a very interesting question.

Try editing the `src` of the iframe to include the tracking code of user *ON LOAD* and therefore passing it through to that instance. This should do the trick.

So for example, if a user comes to your page grapesode.com from AdWords which has an iframe at salesforce.com/form load the iframe as salesforce.com/form?utm_source=adwords and then pass the UTM into a hidden field within your form.

Comment: An event, pageview etc will trigger within the 3rd party iframe, regardless of whether cross domain tracking has been configured correctly, if the iframe content also has tracking for the same property installed. Given that you are unable to track the originating source of the visit, indicates that the cross domain tracking is possibly not correctly passing the linker parameter to the iframe. You may want to take a look at the following page. 
https://www.bounteous.com/insights/2015/11/24/tracking-complex-interactions-in-iframes-embedded-server-side-google-analytics-iframes-pt-4/